# How to check current browser is Alipay mobile browser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if current browser is Alipay mobile browser. If it's not Alipay mobile browser, I will open Alipay App. How could I do that? Thank for any help.
Update: I used this code and it's worked

```
var isAlipayBrowser = false;
document.addEventListener('AlipayJSBridgeReady', function onBridgeReady() { 
    isAlipayBrowser = true;
}, false);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent

Comment: @KaseyChang, Alipay app is different from other Android app